# How do I pass an href to an onClick function in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In the following code

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const handleClick = (path) => {
    if (path === "/about") {
      console.log("I clicked on the About Page");
    }
    if (path === "/posts") {
      console.log("I clicked on the Posts Page");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Hello World.{" "}
      <Link onClick={() => handleClick("/about")} href="/about">
        <a>About</a>
      </Link>
      <Link onClick={() => handleClick("/posts")} href="/posts">
        <a>Posts</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
```

Whenever the about or posts page is clicked, I'd like to `console.log` that I clicked on the page name. Right now, my current implementation does not `console.log` anything. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can move the onClick handler to the `<a> tag`.

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleClick = (e, path) => {
    if (path === "/about") {
      console.log("I clicked on the About Page");
    }
    if (path === "/posts") {
      console.log("I clicked on the Posts Page");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Hello World.{" "}
      <Link href="/">
        <a onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, "/about")}>About</a>
      </Link>{" "}
      <Link href="/">
        <a onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, "/posts")}>Posts</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: this solution is not a proper way to deal with this case, see the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-new-link-with-extra-anchor

Answer (score 6):

### 2021-08 Answer

In **NextJS**,

I did something like that

```
 const Nav = () => {

  const handleLogoClick = async (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent> | undefined, url: string) => {
    e?.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked');
  };


     return (
            <a href="" onClick={(e) => handleLogoClick(e, '/')}>
              {shopData?.logo && <Logo src={shopData?.logo} loading="lazy" />}
            </a>
    )
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

**updating answer to handle race condition between href and onClick**

Since you are redirected when clicking the `<Link>`, I wouldn't try to manage both `href` and `onClick`.

I would do everything on the `handleClick` function, even redirecting the user in a programatically way:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function IndexPage() {
  const router = useRouter()

  const handleClick = (e, path) => {
   e.preventDefault()

    if (path === "/about") {
      console.log("I clicked on the About Page");
      // then you can: 
      // router.push(path)
    }
    if (path === "/posts") {
      console.log("I clicked on the Posts Page");
      // then you can: 
      // router.push(path)
    }
  };
}

  return (
    <div>
      Hello World.{" "}
      <Link onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, "/about")}>
        <a>About</a>
      </Link>
      <Link onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, "/posts")}>
        <a>Posts</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
```

Note that if you do `router.push` right after the console.log, the `console.log` would not be shown, since you are being redirected. But I believe you want to do some extra work before pushing the user, so you can follow this approach anyway.

Comment: I've tried implementing your solution, but I can't see my console.log. Is it because the page redirects to the link and clears the console? https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-router-bfk11?file=/pages/index.js:0-541

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. I will update my answer to handle this case

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But now I am getting the following error: 

Error: Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead.

I will try revising your code and solve the issue.

Comment: You are welcome. Since you are navigating programmatically, the element handling the click doesn't need to be a `<Link>` anymore. It can be a styled `button` or a `span` for example.

Comment: as `href` is required, this solution does not work with `Link` from `next/link`

Answer (score 4):

As of November 2021 you can make the child a functional
component, to use console log:

```
import Link from 'next/link'

// `onClick`, `href`, and `ref` need to be passed to the DOM element
// for proper handling
const MyButton = React.forwardRef(({ onClick, href }, ref) => {
  return (
    <a href={href} onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>
      Click Me
    </a>
  )
})

function Home() {
  return (
    <Link href="/about" passHref>
      <MyButton />
    </Link>
  )
}

export default Home
```

No idea why this needs to be this way.

Answer (score 1):

This is NextJs definition for Link

```
declare function Link(props: React.PropsWithChildren<LinkProps>): React.DetailedReactHTMLElement<{
    onMouseEnter?: React.MouseEventHandler<Element> | undefined;
    onClick: React.MouseEventHandler;
    href?: string | undefined;
    ref?: any;
}, HTMLElement>;
export default Link;
```

You can invoke your custom onClick to the Link's first child's onClick prop. To make it easy to use, we can create our own custom link that wraps nextJS's link.

// aLink.js

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function ALink({ href, onClick, label }) {
    return (
        <Link href={href}>
            <a onClick={() => onClick()}>{label}</a>
        </Link>
    )
}
```

And then import your own ALink instead of nextJS's link!
// NavLink.js

```
import ALink from './aLink';

export default function Nav() {
    return (
        <nav>
            <ALink href='/' onClick={() => customOnClick() label='home' }/>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

Comment: What's the difference of this to adding the onClick directly on the Link component?