# How to overcome warning of "onClick" was passed to <Link> with `href` of `#` but "legacyBehavior" was set in next js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I am working on the next project that has a lot of warnings in the browser console. I don't have any idea why this happens and how I should overcome it. There is much waring like:

> "onClick" was passed to  with `href` of `/discovery/edit` but "legacyBehavior" was set. The legacy behavior requires onClick be set on the child of next/link
> at LinkComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:88:23)
> at span
> at div
> at div
> at C (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@headlessui/react/dist/internal/open-closed.js:8:255)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@headlessui/react/dist/components/disclosure/disclosure.js:16:1808)
> at div
> at nav
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at DashboardTemplate (webpack-internal:///./common/components/templates/DashboardTemplate.js:49:26)
> at EditQuestions (webpack-internal:///./pages/discovery/edit/index.js:45:22)
> at IntercomProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-use-intercom/dist/react-use-intercom.esm.js:228:20)
> at AnalyticWrapper (webpack-internal:///./contexts/AnalyticWrapper.js:33:72)
> at GlobalWrapper (webpack-internal:///./contexts/GlobalWrapper.js:68:62)
> at SessionProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next-auth/react/index.js:417:24)
> at App (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:37:28)
> at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:8:20742)
> at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:8:23635)
> at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:70:9)
> at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:215:26)
> at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:402:27)

I have a sidebar file in my project that return specific one for specific user type:

```
const licensePro = [
{
 name: "Owner Result",
 icon: UsersIcon,
 current: false,
 href: "/dashboard/Owner Result",
 },
 {
  name: "Invite Owner",
  icon: FolderIcon,
  current: false,
  href: "#",
 },
 {
  name: "Model Owner",
  icon: CalendarIcon,
  current: false,
  href: "#",
  },
  {
   name: "Brand Ambassador",
   href: "#",
   icon: InboxIcon,
   current: false,
   },
   {
    name: "Matchmaker",
    icon: ChartBarIcon,
    current: false,
    children: [
      {
         name: "Add matchmaker",
         href: "/dashboard/matchmaker/add-matchmaker",
         current: false,
      },
      {
         name: "Matchmaker List",
         href: "/dashboard/matchmaker/matchmaker-list",
         current: false,
       },
    
     ],
   },
```

And where I mapped it.

```
{licensePro.map((item, i) => (
              <>
                <Link
                  key={i + "sec1"}
                  href={item.href}
                  className={`${
                    item.hintIndex === hintStep ? "z-[70]" : ""
                  } flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium leading-6 rounded-md group text-cyan-100 hover:text-white hover:bg-cyan-600`}
                  passHref
                >
                  <div
                    onClick={() => {
                      localStorage.setItem("openMenu", "off");
                    }}
                    className={`text-cyan-100 cursor-pointer hover:text-white hover:bg-cyan-600 group w-full flex items-center pl-2 pr-1 py-2 text-left text-sm font-medium rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500`}
                  >
                    <item.icon
                      className="w-6 h-6 mr-4 text-cyan-200"
                      aria-hidden="true"
                    />
                    {item.name}
                  </div>
                </Link>
              </>
            ))}
```

Comment: can you attach the code where exactly the error is appearing ...

Comment: @KcH I added some code.

Comment: first of all it's not good to have an onClick to a `div` which is bad in terms of accessibilty ... and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65638840/how-do-i-pass-an-href-to-an-onclick-function-in-nextjs) link if it helps

Comment: @KcH I used `<a>` instead of `div`> but the problem is still alive.

Comment: as I see in other link, why don't you put `onClick` on `Link` directly ?

Comment: Are you sure that's the code generating the warnings? The warning would only appear if you try to set `onClick` directly on the  `Link` component, which you don't seem to be doing in the code you provided.

Comment: Yes, the aobe code is just a simple of all. they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday, and fixed today... Take a look to your imports, maybe there is the problem. I change the Link from next/link to '@mui/material' if you are using mui ofcourse, and the warnings gone!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).